# How to create svn repository from working copy?

Tags: svn

I have working copy

```
svn co svn://server.com/sw copy
```

I search something faster than

```
svnadmin create /tmp/new
svn co file:///tmp/new new_copy
cp -r copy/* new_copy
svn add new_copy/*
svn ci new_copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`svn import`](http://chestofbooks.com/computers/revision-control/subversion-svn/svn-Import-Ref-svn-C-Import.html) command

Answer (score 2):

You can try `svn import`, it commits an unversioned file tree to the repository.

I don't know if it will work well with all of the .svn directories in the original tree being imported into the new repository, but you can use a

```
find . -name '.svn' | xargs rm -rf
```

to wipe those out before the import if you find they are problematic.